# CSS table border spacing inside only

Tags: css, html-table

I have trying to work this out for months, and Google hasn't helped me. I'm trying to have spacing between `<td>` and `<th>` tags in a table, but when I do, it does spacing in the outside. Therefore, the table isn't inline with anything else. So it looks like the table has some padding.

I can't seem to find a solution.

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/Sy4AK/1) is an example of the issue

Comment: how far are you with coding could you add some jsfiddle ?

Answer (score 27):

I optimized the solution with transparent border so it has no more obliquely cut inner borders.

1) let table fill horizontal and collapse the borders:

```
table {
  width: 100%;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}
```

2) Set all borders of table cells to width 0 and prevent background is drawn below the border.

```
td {
  border: 0px solid transparent;
  background-clip: padding-box;
}
```

3) Set inner space with transparent border but not to first row and column.

```
tr > td + td {
  border-left-width: 10px;
}

tr + tr > td {
  border-top-width: 10px;
}
```

here is a [jsbin](http://jsbin.com/mawata/1/edit?html,css,output)

Comment: This is the answer!

Comment: This is definitely the best way to go!

Comment: I'd love to upvote twice...

Answer (score 26):

Had the same problem, the border spacing property was adding space around the table as well, and to my knowledge, there wasn’t anyway to limit it to only ‘the inside’, so I used transparent borders instead:

```
table td {
   border-left: 1em solid transparent;
   border-top: 1em solid transparent;
}
```

This sets ‘border spacing’ as normal, except that there’s ‘unwanted’ spacing at the top and left of the table.

```
table td:first-child {
   border-left: 0;
}
```

Selects the first column.

```
table tr:first-child td {
   border-top: 0;
}
```

Selects the td elements of the first row *(assuming that the top of the table starts with a tr element, change accordingly for th)*.

Comment: While a clever trick, this isn't really useful to anyone who already uses the border properties for the styling of the cells themselves.

Comment: @vsync is correct - the transparent border just shows the background colour of the cell. So it looks like the cell padding is just getting bigger.

Comment: @vsync: It works fine, if you also use the CSS property `background-clip: padding-box;`. No background is drawn below the border (background extends to the outside edge of the padding).

Answer (score 21):

I found a way to do this with negative margins and improves on Steven's answer in that it lets you make the table take up 100% even if it doesn't have enough content. The solution is to make the table width 100% and use a negative margin on a containing element:

```
#container {
    margin: 0 -10px;
}
table {
    border-collapse: separate;
    border-spacing: 10px;
}
td, th {
    background-color: #ccf;
    padding: 5px;
}
```

[See it as a jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/marcstober/60dnac4a/1/)

Comment: @vsync what do you mean exactly? It is still working for me (in Firefox) in the jsFiddle I linked to with a table width 100%.

Comment: ho sorry, yeah cause you are wrapping it with a `div` so it works, but for the table itself, negative margin on both sides wouldn't work..I didn't explain myself, my bad

Comment: @vsync Yes, you do need to wrap it with a div for this particular solution to work.

Comment: Yes, I do know you need to wrap it with a div for this particular solution to work. But it's always nice to hear it again.

Comment: Excellent! Thanks.

Comment: Dear Lord! This is genius :D I tried almost anything except wrapping it in a new div.

Comment: This is the best solution if you need to style the borders of the TD's.

Answer (score 10):

Similar to what Steven Vachon said, negative margin may be your best bet.

Alternatively, you can use `calc()` to fix the problem.

CSS:

```
/* border-collapse and border-spacing are css equivalents to <table cellspacing="5"> */

.boxmp {
    width:100%;
    border-collapse:separate;
    border-spacing:5px 0;
}

/* border-spacing includes the left of the first cell and the right of the last cell
    negative margin the left/right and add those negative margins to the width
    ios6 requires -webkit-
    android browser doesn't support calc()
    100.57% is the widest that I could get without a horizontal scrollbar at 1920px wide */

.boxdual {
    margin:0 -5px;
    width:100.57%;
    width:-webkit-calc(100% + 10px);
    width:calc(100% + 10px);
}
```

Just add whatever margin you take off or the width will be too narrow (100% isn't wide enough).

Comment: I would consider this the best answer as calc is widely supported now.

Answer (score 4):

### Here is the cool hack to do that

```
table {
    border-collapse: inherit;
    border-spacing: 10px;
    width: calc(100% + 20px);
    margin-left: -10px;
}
```

use `margin-left: -10px;` to remove left padding but in the right there will be 20px padding. Now to update it use `width: calc(100% + 20px);`

Answer (score 3):

Use negative margins and a container with positive padding.

```
#container {
    box-sizing: border-box; /* avoids exceeding 100% width */
    margin: 0 auto;
    max-width: 1024px;
    padding: 0 10px;    /* fits table overflow */
    width: 100%;
}

table {
    border-collapse: separate;
    border-spacing: 10px;
    margin: 0 -10px;    /* ejects outer border-spacing */
    min-width: 100%;    /* in case content is too short */
}

td {
    width: 25%;     /* keeps it even */
}
```

Just make sure that you have substantial content for it to stretch the table to 100% width, or else it'll be 20px too narrow.

More info: [svachon.com/blog/inside-only-css-table-border-spacing/](http://www.svachon.com/blog/inside-only-css-table-border-spacing/)

Comment: This does not work for tables which by themselves do not expand to the 100% width. See http://jsfiddle.net/EXe8z/ (just cut off the last two columns). You'll end up with triple padding on the right side and normal padding on the left side.

Comment: I already stated this in my answer: "Just make sure that you have substantial content for it to stretch the table to 100% width". Most applications I build that use tables have more than single-digit-length content.