# CSS - Border only inside the table with the cell spacing

Tags: html, css

I am trying to figure out how to add border only inside the table with the cell spacing. When I do:

```
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  border-spacing: 4px;
}
table td, table th {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

It works almost fine just cells without spacing. How to achieve that?

Thanks

Comment: It is unclear what you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: related - http://stackoverflow.com/q/8806161/104380

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're trying to write CSS rules for tables on which you've defined the `cellspacing` attribute, a solution could be this :

```
table[cellspacing] {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  border-spacing: 4px;
}
table[cellspacing] td, table[cellspacing] th {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

But it would be much cleaner and more efficient to give a class to your table (`<table class="withspace">`). So you would more classically do

```
table.withspace {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  border-spacing: 4px;
}
table.withspace td, table.withspace th {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

EDIT : just in case, if what you want is simply to have some space in your cells, add a padding value in your css :

```
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  border-spacing: 4px;
}
table td, table th {
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding: 4px;
}
```

Comment: In fact I don't get what you're trying to do. Just add cellspacing ?

Comment: Yes, cellspacing but with cell borders only

Comment: See my EDIT. Is it what you were looking for ?

Comment: no, I am looking for cellspacing! Cellpadding is not what I need

Comment: I don't get what you want. But maybe this wizard will help you : http://www.somacon.com/p141.php

Comment: ok, see table bellow on that page? January..etc. It has 1 border around all cells and each cell has border. So I do not need border around all cells just cell around  border. See?

Answer (score 1):

The CSS code posted is correct and causes borders around cells (but around the table as a whole) and 4px spacing between cells, on conforming browsers. I suppose you were testing this on IE 7 or older, which do not support the [`border-spacing`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/border-spacing) property.

I’m afraid there is no simpler workaround than to create a table without any borders and put an inner element inside each cell, making that cell occupy the entire cell except small margins, and draw borders around the inner elements. This probably gets ugly, so I’d rather let the presentation on IE 7 be suboptimal.

(For some reason, `border-spacing` does not seem to work in jsfiddle. Probably some general rule overrides a normal attempt to set the property.)

Comment: It's probably jsFiddle enabling normalize.css by default (which you can toggle in the leftmost pane), which has a `border-collapse: collapse;` rule.